# Calculate limit with definite integration

Tags: integration, limits

We were given the task to find the result of following limit within the topic of integration, definite one to be specific, so solution have to correlate in some with with the mentioned topic, however don't see any integrals here. Do you have any ideas?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\left(\sum_{t=1}^{n} \frac{t}{t^2+n^2}\right)$$
P.S It may be connected on theory level only..

Comment: Use `\lim`  and `\left(, \right)` to tailor parentheses to match the height of what they contain.  Click on "edit" to see the better formatting of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is related to the Riemann sum definition of Riemann integrals.

Divide the top and bottom of your fraction by $n^2$:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{t}{t^2+n^2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=1}^n \frac 1n \cdot \frac{\frac tn}{\big(\frac tn \big)^2+1}$$

With this, we see that this summation is taking the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ and chopping the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ pieces (each of width $\frac 1n$), then summing up the areas of the rectangular pieces.

It follows that, when we take the limit to infinity, we get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=1}^n \frac{t}{t^2+n^2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=1}^n \frac 1n \cdot \frac{\frac tn}{\big(\frac tn \big)^2+1}=\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^2+1} \, dx=\bigg[\frac 12 \ln (x^2+1)\bigg]^1_0=\frac 12 \ln(2)$$